# EntityManager unwanted background commit

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, glassfish

I have a strange problem on one of my glassfish server. Have a look on this piece of code:

```java
userTransaction.begin();

MyEntity entity = new MyEntity(12345);
//setting values..
entityManager.persist(entity);

MyEntity persistedEntity = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM MyEntity p WHERE p.idpk=12345").getSingleResult();
//...

userTransaction.commit(); //OK => the tuple is in the DB
```

Now there is a business problem and the transaction needs to be rollbacked.

```java
userTransaction.begin();

MyEntity entity = new MyEntity(12345);
//setting values..
entityManager.persist(entity);

MyEntity persistedEntity = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM MyEntity p WHERE p.idpk=12345").getSingleResult();
//...

//Business problem => rollback
userTransaction.rollback(); //ERROR => the tuple 12345 is in the DB !
```

Even if the rollback seems to work (no exception raised or strange log output), the tuple has been committed in the database...
To search where the problem is, I tried the following code:

```java
userTransaction.begin();

MyEntity entity = new MyEntity(12345);
//setting values..
entityManager.persist(entity);

//Business problem => rollback
userTransaction.rollback(); //OK => the tuple 12345 is NOT in the DB !
```

With this code (the entity is not retrieved), the tuple is not committed to the database, which is the correct behaviour. Let's go further:

```java
userTransaction.begin();

MyEntity entity = new MyEntity(12345);
//setting values..
entityManager.persist(entity);

MyEntity persisted = entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, 12345);
//...

//Business problem => rollback
userTransaction.rollback(); //OK => the tuple 12345 is NOT in DB
```

In this last case, the result is still correct and there is no tuple committed to the database. It seems the EntityManager makes a magic [unwanted] commit when retrieving the entity with a query...
I also tried to make a query on another table and that doesn't cause the wrong commit (the rollback works). Moreover, I tried to reproduce the problem on my own server, and there is no problem: all the rollbacks work correctly. Hence, it should really be a server configuration problem.

For information, it is a glassfish v2.1.1 running on linux. The EntityManager is in FlushModeType.AUTO.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks & best regards !

Comment: What database are you using? The table with the issue has the same DDL on both databases (if they are different)?

Comment: The problem occurs on MySQL 5.0.51a (on a Debian x64). I also tested on another server with Weblogic/Oracle10g and there is no problem: the transaction is rollbacked correctly.
The DDL is exactly the same on the server (moreover, I tested locally with the same data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found where was the problem: in the JDBC Connection Pool, there is a section "Transaction" where the option "Non Transactional Connections" was enabled... Simply removing this option made the whole thing work :)

Answer (score 2):

Found some discussion which seems to explain some of what you're seeing:

Via P-331 of EJB3 In Action Book:

> By default, the database flush mode is set to AUTO. This means that
>   the Entity-Manager performs a flush operation automatically as needed.
>   In general, this occurs at the end of a transaction for
>   transaction-scoped EntityManagers and when the persistence context is
>   closed for  application-managed or extendedscope EntityManagers. **In
>   addition, if entities with pending changes are used in a query, the
>   persistence  provider will flush changes to the database before
>   executing the query.**  **If the flush mode is set to COMMIT, the
>   persistence provider will  only synchronize with the database when the
>   transaction commits.** However, you should be careful with this, as it
>   will be your responsibility  to synchronize entity state with the
>   database before executing a query. If you don’t do this and an
>   EntityManager query returns stale  entities from the database, the
>   application can wind up in an inconsistent state.

P-353 EJB3 In Action Book states:

> If the **Query is set to FlushModeType.COMMIT**, the effect of updates
>   made to entities in the persistence context is not defined by the
>   specification, and the actual behavior is implementation specific.

Perhaps try toggling the flush mode on the query returned by

`entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM MyEntity p WHERE p.idpk=12345").getSingleResult();`

or on the entity manager itself and see if that changes anything?

Some further discussion here:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/475041/ORM/databases/EntityManager-setFlushMode-COMMIT-Vs-Query

Comment: Hello, I already investigated this solution. In my case it works, but lead to other problems (especially, in FlushModeType.COMMIT, the behaviour of update queries are unspecified). I think the problem is really not in the FlushModeType in fact but in the server's configuration...

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this:

```
MyEntity persisted = entityManager.persist(entity);
```

Comment: Yep that would work, but however the application is really big and the persist is done in another part and I can't retrieve directly the entity...

Comment: Yes. The problem is really "why the transaction's rollback doesn't work in this case". I guess there is some configuration (either in MySQL or Glassfish) that make this happend.

Comment: I can't see why you can't make use of the returned entity from `em.persist()`. It doesn't matter what size the application is, if it is done correctly using AOP/OOP or whatever this should be possible.